# Let's get critical: Feb 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Writers Stack Exchange](http://writers.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://writers.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What is a reasonable amount of time to spend writing a product overview?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/10002/what-is-a-reasonable-amount-of-time-to-spend-writing-a-product-overview)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Is it legal to use an old painting on the cover of a book?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/10006/is-it-legal-to-use-an-old-painting-on-the-cover-of-a-book)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to highlight a main character among several points of view?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9991/how-to-highlight-a-main-character-among-several-points-of-view)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Dates and numbers in newspaper articles](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9995/dates-and-numbers-in-newspaper-articles)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [tinyURL seen as risky by readers?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/10097/tinyurl-seen-as-risky-by-readers)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Create and publish collection of public domain poems from 19th century](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9861/create-and-publish-collection-of-public-domain-poems-from-19th-century)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Can the term "Glorified delivery" be used to signify giving birth?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9997/can-the-term-glorified-delivery-be-used-to-signify-giving-birth)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Is there a great manual for technical and scientific writing?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/10031/is-there-a-great-manual-for-technical-and-scientific-writing)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [What does "telling and not showing" mean?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9901/what-does-telling-and-not-showing-mean)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Does this opening relate to the message?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/10016/does-this-opening-relate-to-the-message)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

Answer (score 2):

Having looked at the questions, the first thing I think we need to do is be better about helping people write good questions...it seemed that a lot of the questions were deemed to general or off topic right off the cuff and I am not saying those judgements are incorrect but I would say we definitely need to find ways to re-work that content to make it something that can be discussed/add value.

The answers to questions appear to be of consistent or higher quality with what is out there on the web, but the volume seems to be lacking a little.

Comment: Writers is a particularly difficult site to write good questions for, since the act of writing is *so* tied up with opinion and subjective decisions. This may be part of the problem.

Comment: Agreed.  So do you allow more subjective questions and then let the majority decision/vote bring answers to the fore or do we continue locking these types of questions?